# Using the chat reply function without pinging

Tags: feature-request, chat

If you use the reply function in chat, it currently does two things.

1. It links your message to an earlier message.
2. It pings the person who wrote the message you are linking to.

In some cases, it can be useful to decouple these two. Specifically, one might want to link to someone elses message without alerting them via a ping.

Comment: I feel like this might be overcomplicating it...

Comment: I have often wanted this myself, and heard others mention wanting it. It would be particularly useful in a busy chatroom with several conversations in parallel, where the subject isn't coherent enough to warrant a separate chat room

Answer (score 14):

I'd use this feature at least a couple of times per hour (spent chatting).

I see at least two use cases for this:

1. Providing context in a crowded room.

   When multiple people are chatting, this can get confusing without hitting the reply button. Causing a ping with every other line I type is probably going to annoy my chat partners, so I don't do it. But I'd like to.
2. Sometimes, you want to reply to somebody's aged post, but not actually to that person.

   A ping is completely undesired in that case.